# Showing thousands of ImageViews in android

Tags: android, imageview

I need to load a lots of images (3500 images) to my android app (and then I will rotate with each of them in the application). But when I load each of them separately (creating new ImageView which I add to the array) then it takes about 10 seconds to load. I have tried to inflate them from XMLs since there is only 8 different images which I use but no visible changes.

I would be really grateful for any advice how to load it faster.

EDIT: I am creating a grid of hexagons, each hexagon is consisted of 6 triangles (this way I need to store only 8 different triangle images instead of storing image for each different hexagon). After the grid is loaded user can resize it. I need to load all the grid cell at once because there are many constrains between them. Also only operation I will do with the hexagons is to rotate them.

Comment: Can you describe your use case further?  Loading 3500 ImageViews all at once is probably not a good idea.  There are several constructs in android that can help with this type of problem.

Comment: I have edited my question. The grid is 24x24 hexagons. I don't know about any constructs which I could use, so thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Using `ImageView` widgets is inappropriate in this case IMHO. Create your own custom `View` that knows how to handle your 24x24 hex grid. Or, use any number of existing game engines that handle maps.

Comment: I have solve it by creating my own View. Also I made the texture twice as small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cashing for bitmap images, the following tutorial link is helpful.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Can I load each of the 8 images to cache and for example clone them for the rest of the grid? I have bigger problem with initial loading, when it is loaded I don't see it glitching that much when resizing the whole layout.